# I need a NodeJs Open Source Server to Download and Run on Windows NodeJS Server

Tags: node.js, windows, server, sms, open-source

I have a question on NodeJs. I am developing a customer application that needs to send some **SMS notifications** to my clients. Now I am looking for an open source NodeJs SMS server that will allow my application to send SMSs to my **customers.** Please suggest any **working open source SMS server** that supports NodeJs. Please I have tried to search around I have heard of RapidSMS and Kannel while Kannel have a very long documentation which is hard to understand. I need one that supports NodeJs and works on **windows server**/ but it can be **Linux** if thats the case. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using npm you should be able to use any of the following providers: (Does not matter whether you run it on Windows Server or Linux)

1. https://www.nexmo.com/
2. A free option to try out: https://www.codementor.io/nicks/send-a-tex-sms-using-node-js-a084719np